# How to search a word on two table if have or not by php query

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to find out my userid from two table by username where username have already stayed in table2 or not. That means if username match in any table my query collect its userid.

```
table 1:  username --- userid  > john --- 100

table 2:  username --- userid  > colin --- 101
```

I read many article here nut I cannot understand what should I do.

*Now think: I need john's uesrid,*

So I tried:

```
$username = "john";

$q = "SELECT userid FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.username = '$username' or table2.username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
```

Comment: I think that'll lead to an error `unambiguous userid`

Comment: What is your native language? You can look up `INNER JOIN` and `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: So what error it gives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you want to check if the name already exist in one of your tables.

Here is the easy php code:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 include 'db_connect.php';

 $check_1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE Username = '$Username'");
 $check_2 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Table_2 WHERE Username = '$Username'");

 if(mysqli_num_rows($check_1)==0){
     //Didnt exist in table 1

 }

 else if(mysqli_num_rows($check_2)==0){
     //No result in table 2 either.
 }
 else{
     //what you want to do if the username doesnt exist
 }
```

Let me know how it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could select both `userid` fields and afterwards look if one of them is set:

```
$username = "john";

$q = "SELECT table1.userid AS userid1,table2.userid AS userid2 FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.username = '$username' or table2.username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$username = "john";

$q = "SELECT table1.userid FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.username=table2.username WHERE table1.username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
```

JOIN will join table2 to table1 if the maching pattern (table1.username=table2.username) equals true or exclude this row from table1 from results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION clause

```
$q="SELECT t1.userid FROM table1 as t1 WHERE username='$username' UNION SELECT t2.userid FROM table2 as t2 WHERE username='$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left join**

```
$username = "username";

$q = "SELECT userid 
      FROM table1
      LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.username = table2.username
      WHERE table1.username = '$username' or table2.username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
```